# Multiple variable assignment in q

Tags: kdb, k

This code looks like multiple variable assignment:

```
d:`a`b`c!1 2 3
d[`a`b]:10 20
```

Why is it working this way? And why it is not the same as `(a;b):10 20` (which doesn't work)?

I suppose the 2nd line will make only *temporary* assignment - do not actually replace values. But it will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indexing at top level and assigning new values so it would be the same as:

```
q)@[`d;`a`b;:;10 20]
`d
```

which also works for global variables in the root context

```
q)@[`.;`a`b;:;100 200]
`.
q)a
100
q)b
200
```